# Do we need dedicated webservers or can we simply use modern application servers?

Tags: webserver, weblogic

I am planning to design an application which will require both web server and application server (Java EE based). Modern application servers like Weblogic, Websphere, JBOSS can provide support for both application server and web server. However I have seen many applications where the deployment architecture provides a segregation of web server and application server as a separate entity.

I would like to know:

- What is the architectural benefit of segregating the web server and app server as a separate entity?
- e.g. Assuming we are going to use weblogic as a web sever and app server do you think if there is any concern for large applications?

Answer (score 0):

There is several resons to use a dedicated web server for static content:

- In most case a web server is already present infront of the application server (reverce proxy), it is needed if the app server is clustered.  So as it is already present.
- If the static content is important (size and trafic), puting it in web server allow to scall the content and the application separeatly.
- Historicly pure Java app server was slower that native web server, now NIO allow the same access to system call sending file directly to a socket without going back and forward between system and user mode.

So I think you should start with the contend delivered by the app server and complexify the system if it help you to solve issues you actualy enconter.